# BASH- Find files of the same size, use cksum, delete dupe but keep it's name as symbolic link

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, automation

Good day to you!I am an intern and just starting to learn bash Scripting (thanks bash.academy!) and am attempting to create a script that does the following;

1. Find files of the same size
2. Determine if the contents of the file is a duplicate via cksum
3. Delete duplicate file, keeping both file names, turning the deleted file into a symbolic link to the remaining file.

Background on what's going on; there is a program the generates these files, and it's generating duplicates in large quantities. It creates a pair of files that have the exact same data contained, but different names and we have programs that rely on the duplicate files (again, we can't change those programs to check the non duplicate file), hence why I have to turn the deleted file into a symbolic link. I appreciate any suggestions, cheers!

```
`e#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /path/to/files
ls -l -S | sort -k 5 -n #sort file sizes in revers order
cksum /path/to/files/* |        #File duplication verification
  awk ' { if( $2 in arr) 
            {print "duplicates ", $3, arr[$2], "duplicate filesize = ", $2} 
              else 
            {arr[$2]=$3} }' 
`
```

Comment: Show us the code that you already tried

Comment: Please ask a [mcve]

Comment: `there is a program the generates these files`  Where? In the same directory?

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness and lack of code, getting code to post now! (Not on my workstation at the moment) It will be posted here momentarily, I was not anticipating such a quick response. You guys rock

Comment: @mona-sax  No, it is submitting the data into the server. I am not actually allowed to view the program, and since the values contained in these files are stored as hash, I don't know what they actually are... Also, thanks for the link, I should've checked before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the question is not immensely clear, I hope below script helps:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Removing the duplicate files based on md5 hash based asscociative arrays
declare -A file_list # Note -A is for associative array
# The above associate array will have the below format
# file_list=([md5-hash]=filename)
duplicate_remover()
{
 md5_data=( $(md5sum "$1") )
 # md5sum gives the output in 'hash filename' format. See Reference 1
 check_exist=${file_list["X${md5_data[0]}"]+exists}
 # Above command check if the array element with the given key already exists in 'file_list' array.
 # We have used shell parameter expansion. See Reference 2
 if [ "$check_exist" = "exists" ]
 then
   ln -fs "${file_list["X${md5_data[0]}"]}" "$1"
   # Above steps turns duplicates to symbolic links. 
   # Note the '-f' with 'ln' forces rewrite if dest. file is already present
 else
   file_list+=(["X${md5_data[0]}"]="$1")
   # If the file is not already in the array, we add it using [key]=value construct.
 fi
}
#Our driver part below uses 'find' command to feed files into 'duplicate_remover' function
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | while read -r -d '' filename
do
   duplicate_remover "$filename"
done
```

**References**

1. See `md5sum` [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/md5sum).
2. See the usage of `${var+stuff}` in shell [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

**Notes**

1. I assumed that all the files are present in the same directory, if not take out the `-maxdepth 1` from find.
2. The files that come first with `find` will be preserved and the rest will be converted to links.

Comment: It helps immensely! I greatly appreciate all the comments, makes this a lot easier to learn. I attempted to up vote, but not enough points yet.

Comment: @AngeloGeruso : You may accept the answer by clicking the tick mark right down to the votes then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can identify files with the file command using the "-type f" and "ls" parameter, this way you should get the size and name of the file.

The output can be filtered using an AWK script, printing only the desired columns.

Once you have this info you sould sort it based on size and getting the duplicated filesizes.

For the duplicated filesizes you must get the checksum, if you find a duplicated then you only have to remove one file and create the link.

Just keep in mind that you must process only files and not links, becuase you could delete the file already linked.

Comment: cksum /path/to/files/* |
  awk ' { if( $2 in arr) 
            {print "duplicates ", $3, arr[$2], "duplicate filesize = ", $2} 
              else 
            {arr[$2]=$3} }'

Comment: That's the awk script that I have, trying to figure out how to erase the duplicate file, but keep the name as a symbolic link... that is the main issue